# Loop without allocation in Go

Tags: loops, go

In Go, if I want to do something 500 times, but I don't need to use the index, is there a way to loop without allocating an integer?

Like:

```
for i := 0; i < 500; i++ {
    PlayRandomGame()
}
```

I don't need or want to allocate `i` there.

Comment: You shouldn't care too much about how many variables you use. Any other way to implement this loop is going to use a counter anyway.

Answer (score 8):

Nothing in that code requires `i` to be allocated on the heap. It's likely either on the stack, freed when it goes out of scope, or in a register, and in either case not creating garbage. (If you're curious about how this is possible, the technique is called [escape analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_analysis).)
You can see it in [how TotalAlloc doesn't increase in this sample program](http://play.golang.org/p/UnA10lM2oP):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "runtime"
)

func loop() {
    for i := 0; i < 500; i++ {
    }
}

func main() {
    m1, m2 := new(runtime.MemStats), new(runtime.MemStats)
    runtime.ReadMemStats(m1)
    loop()
    runtime.ReadMemStats(m2)
    fmt.Println("TotalAlloc delta was", m2.TotalAlloc - m1.TotalAlloc)
}
```

A counter's necessary to make sure you do 500 iterations of a loop one way or the other, so even if you found some way to make the counter implied (`r := make([]struct{}, 500); for range r {...}`, say), there'd be no variable name but still be a counter under the covers.

Answer (score 2):

If you hate counters, you can use this:

```
for _ = range make([]struct{}, 500) {
    PlayRandomGame()
}
```

But the variant with a counter is more idiomatic.

Comment: Or, since Go 1.4 `for range make([]struct{}, 500) { }`